# Exporting Game Bible pages in Prison Architect?

Tags: prison-architect

The game bible pages that we collect contain design notes that I'm really curious to read.  But reading them in-game is greatly inconvenient. I'd love for a way to export them and read on a kindle or something.

Is there a way for me to do it? From the game files perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Prison Architect\collectables.dat -> open this as archive (7-zip will do).
Inside it is: data\gamebible\

The password for the archive is

> `SnitchesGetStitches`